# Failed to compile program when trying to define member function conditionally using std::enable_if in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, class-template

I'am writing a simple class with some member functions as usual, and this time I'am trying to define a member function only when the template parameters of the class meet some conditions, but the codes seems unable to be compiled in both g++ and vs2019. The simplest demo is like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int RowCnt, int ColCnt, typename ValueType = double>
class Matrix {
public:
  template <std::enable_if_t<RowCnt == ColCnt, int> = 0>
  void GetInverseMatrix() {}

private:
  ValueType data[RowCnt][ColCnt];
};

int main() {
  Matrix<3, 3> a;
  Matrix<3, 5> b; // Compilation would fail here
  return 0;
}
```

Error outputs from g++ are like this:

```
test_enable_if_valid.cc: In instantiation of ‘class Matrix<3, 5>’:
test_enable_if_valid.cc:15:16:   required from here
test_enable_if_valid.cc:7:8: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, int>’
    7 |   void GetInverseMatrix() {}
      |
```

While vs2019 told similar things:

```
1>D:\labs\enable_if_test_1\main.cpp(7,1): error C2938: 'std::enable_if_t<false,int>' : Failed to specialize alias template
1>D:\labs\enable_if_test_1\main.cpp(6,17): message : see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::enable_if_t<false,int>' being compiled
1>D:\labs\enable_if_test_1\main.cpp(15,15): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Matrix<3,5,double>' being compiled
```

In my opinion, compilers could have skipped the compilation of `GetInverseMatrix()` function because there are no calls for `Matrix<3, 5>::GetInverseMatrix()`, or unless the SFINA rules should work. Could you please tell me why I am wrong or why compilers behave differently from my expectation above?

Thank you in advance, and any information would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

SFINAE works when substituting the explicitly specified or deduced *template argument* for the *template parameter*.

The function template `GetInverseMatrix` has one template parameter, and the parameter itself is invalid unless `RowCnt == ColCnt`, before any substitution even takes place.

Validity of a template parameter may depend on a preceding template parameter *of that same template*, so this is OK:

```
template <int a, std::enable_if_t<a==42, int> = 0>
void foo() {}
```

But this is not OK:

```
template <int a>
struct bar
{
   template <std::enable_if_t<a==42, int> = 0>
   void foo() {}
};
bar<0> b;
```

A function template that is not called is not instantiated, but any function template must have at least a valid template parameter list.

One way to write this template would be

```
template<int R = RowCnt, int C = ColCnt> 
  std::enable_if_t<R == C>
    GetInverseMatrix() {}
```